2 Commuting, Continuous mappings from a closed interval onto itself doesn't always have a common fixed point.
The question is as such:

If two continuous mappings $f$ and $g$ of a closed interval into itself commute, that is, $f\circ g=g\circ f$, then they do not always have a common fixed point.

-- Zorich Mathematical Analysis I
This is a similar question:
How prove this they have a common fixed point
I have also asked here on mathoverflow. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/473215/constructing-commuting-functions-on-closed-interval-onto-itself-that-doesnt-hav

What is your definition of an interval? Is it supposed to be closed, open, neither?

@MoisheKohan It depends, I need an counterexample, and given my understanding of the problem, it could be closed open or neither.

They could, but they do not: The answers are different depending on what kind of intervals you consider.

@MoisheKohan It should be closed, I discovered that it is a translation problem after checking chinese edition.

see for example https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-137-00/S0002-9947-1969-0236331-5/S0002-9947-1969-0236331-5.pdf

It seems like we need a counter-example, right?
So what if take $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x^2 +x +1$ it is continuous and $g: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $g(x) = x$

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

@OwenAn: Given lack of restrictions in your question, the real line is an interval.

@OwenAn R is open interval
